# Image printing using DPP-350 Bluetooth Printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

For my android project I'm using [DPP-350](http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/DPP-350/2/162#) bluetooth printer and [PrinterSample](https://github.com/NeoCarvalho/PrinterSample) project. I'm able to print plaint text and bar codes but unable to print images. I get bluetooth connectivity error on my Galaxy S5 while printing images only. Can anybody, who have used this printer in android apps, tell me the correct code of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

There are four switches under the battery. Turning fourth switch on resolved my problem.